# What do the areas under the graphs in a `kdeplot` mean when several graphs are drawn simultaneously from the same dataframe?

Tags: visualization, seaborn

Suppose I have a dataframe documenting the offering prices in USD of a certain product in a certain market at a certain time. The product is manufactured by one of two manufacturers: `M1` and `M2`. The prices of items vary per item, so that two different items that were manufactured by the same manufacturer may be offered for different prices.

The dataframe consists of two columns: `manufacturer` and `price`. The `manufacturer` column is categorical and contains one of two values: `M1` or `M2`, whereas the `price` column contains numerical data consisting of positive decimal numbers.

Suppose there are 100 rows in the dataframe, and suppose 30 of these rows have `M1` as the manufacturer, and the rest of the rows have `M2` as the manufacturer.

Suppose I now visualize this table using `Seaborn`'s `kdeplot` function, using the function's `hue` parameter to draw two graphs simultaneously in the same plot, one graph for each manufacturer.

[image: A kdeplot of two subsets of rows from the same dataframe]

If I now calculate the area under each of these graphs, will the area under the graph visualizing the `M1` data be 0.3 and the area under the other graph be 0.7, mirroring the different percentages of entries in the table ascribed to each manufacturer? Or will the areas under both graphs be 1.0 as the case should be if each of them represents a probability density function?